# Snowflake Syntax - Unexpected space character in Syntax

Tags: sql, syntax, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Query

```
select sis.subject_code||'_'||LEFT(REPLACE(sis.SIS_TERM_ID,0,''),LENGTH(sis.SIS_TERM_ID) - 4)||''|| REPLACE(SUBSTR(sis.SIS_TERM_ID, 8, 8),'','') 
from TableX;
```

Result looks like the following
XXXX888543_134 1 ---there is a space before the last value. I am not sure where this is being derived from. Any ideas on what I could modify in the string above please.

Comment: I have tried various other syntax such as select sis.subject_code||'_'||REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(LEFT(REPLACE(sis.SIS_TERM_ID,0,''),LENGTH(sis.SIS_TERM_ID) - 4),
SUBSTR(sis.SIS_TERM_ID, 8, 8)),'','')

Comment: Resolved. There was an issue when replacing the 0 with ''. It was causing a mis-aligned value. Resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the space is really a space, how about doing the `replace()` across the whole string?

```
select replace(sis.subject_code || '_' || LEFT(REPLACE(sis.SIS_TERM_ID, 0, ''), LENGTH(sis.SIS_TERM_ID) - 4) || SUBSTR(sis.SIS_TERM_ID, 8, 8), '', '')
```

It is unclear whether the replace is coming from the last element or the one before it.  But you don't seem to want any spaces in the string.